# Como listar correctamente los widgets dentro de un QLayout

Tags: python, pyqt

Estimados,
 Vengo ante ustedes con un problema que me esta molestando actualmente. Estoy tratando de crear un calendario personalizado en Qt, dado que el `QCalendarWidget` no puede ser modificado ni estilizado, estoy haciendo el propio. 
 El problema es cuando intento conectar los botones de fecha. Para tratar de obtener el boton precionado intento listarlos desde el contendor principal de ellos que es un `QGirdLayout`, pero al hacerlo siempre me retorna el mismo widget sin importar la posicion de este.

Adjunto el codigo e imagen de consola.

```
import calendar
import sys
import time

from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QGridLayout
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPushButton
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget


class DayButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, day):
        QPushButton.__init__(self)
        self.setText(str(day))
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(40, 40))


class Calendar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.today = time.strftime("%x").split("/")

        self.__grid = QGridLayout()
        self.__grid.setSpacing(4)
        self.setCalendar()

        self.setLayout(self.__grid)

    def setCalendar(self):
        selectedDate = calendar.monthrange(int(self.today[2]), int(self.today[0]))

        counter, day = 0, 1
        for i in range(6):
            for j in range(7):
                if counter < selectedDate[0] or day > selectedDate[1]:
                    counter += 1
                    continue
                self.number = DayButton(str(day))
                self.number.released.connect(self.checkChecked)
                self.__grid.addWidget(self.number, i, j)
                day += 1

    def checkChecked(self):
        for item in range(self.__grid.count()):
            print self.__grid.itemAt(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = Calendar()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Como se observa, siempre retorna el mismo objeto, el cual ni siquiera es el tipo de widget que estoy agregando.

[image: consola]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para listar todos los items de un `QGridLayout` puedes crear un generador para iterar sobre ellos usando `QGridLayout.itemAt(int index).widget()`.

En tu caso puedes transformar el método `checkChecked` de la siguiente forma:

```
def checkChecked(self):
    items = (self.__grid.itemAt(item).widget() for item in range(self.__grid.count()))
    for item in items:
        print item
```

Con esto obtenemos la siguiente salida tipo:

> <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3836168>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3836AF8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3836C18>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3836438>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833708>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B38333A8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833678>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B38338B8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833E58>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833948>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833798>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833CA8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B38334C8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B38335E8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833438>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833558>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833D38>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833828>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833B88>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833EE8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833F78>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833DC8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833AF8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B38339D8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B38331F8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833168>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833288>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B3833048>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B38330D8>
>   <**main**.DayButton object at 0x00000261B382E288>

Puedes usar esto para modificar los objetos (en tu caso los botones), por ejemplo, el siguiente método cambia el texto de todos los botones por `S`:

```
def checkChecked(self):
    items = (self.__grid.itemAt(item).widget() for item in range(self.__grid.count()))
    for item in items:
        item.setText('S')
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, estuve peleando con ello hace días :) funcionó perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas obtener que boton ha sido presionado no es necesario usar el gridlayout, una forma elegante es usar la función `sender()` que retorna el objeto que emitio la señal.

```
def checkChecked(self):
    obj = self.sender()
    print obj.text()
```

Código completo:

```
import calendar
import sys
import time

from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QGridLayout
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPushButton
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget


class DayButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, day):
        QPushButton.__init__(self)
        self.setText(str(day))
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(40, 40))


class Calendar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.today = time.strftime("%x").split("/")

        self.__grid = QGridLayout()
        self.__grid.setSpacing(4)
        self.setCalendar()

        self.setLayout(self.__grid)

    def setCalendar(self):
        selectedDate = calendar.monthrange(int(self.today[2]), int(self.today[0]))

        counter, day = 0, 1
        for i in range(6):
            for j in range(7):
                if counter < selectedDate[0] or day > selectedDate[1]:
                    counter += 1
                    continue
                self.number = DayButton(str(day))
                self.number.released.connect(self.checkChecked)
                self.__grid.addWidget(self.number, i, j)
                day += 1

    def checkChecked(self):
        obj = self.sender()
        print obj.text()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Calendar()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: La respuesta es útil pero necesito obtener los objetos dentro para trabajar con cada uno de ellos debido a una comprobación que debo hacer. Igual con sender puedo trabajar en otras necesidades que estaban viniendo :) gracias por el aporte :)